# Notation: Elementwise cropping for vectors

Tags: notation

I am looking for a notation for following function: A vector $\vec{a}$ is normalized using L2-norm. But if the value of one element is bigger then a hysteresis an other value $h$ is used. For example after normalization $\vec{a} = [1, 2, 3, 4]$  and the hysteresis is $3$ then the final vector looks like this: $\vec{a} = [1, 2, 3, 3]$. How can I write this down in a correct mathematical notation. It is basically a "element wise" defined function for a vector. I guess it should somehow look like this:

$$\vec{a} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      h & element > h \\
      \frac{\vec{a}}{\sqrt{||\vec{a}||^2_2 + \epsilon^2}} & else wise\\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

Comment: "min" notation is classical but you should add that is to be understood elementwise ; here it would be: $\min((1,2,3,4),3*(1,1,1,1))$

Answer (score 0):

Use an index:
$$a_i'=\min(a_i,h)$$